# How to write MySql query with multiple data orders?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am working on an application for an organization.
Here i have some events in database table. Now client requirements for their view are as follow.

1. First event should be today's event (If there is any)
2. Then upcoming events should be from todays date. Like if today
   01-11-2011 then next event should be of 02-11-2011(if there is any)
   and next one should be of 03-11-2011 and so on....
3. Once all upcoming events have been listed, you can display old
   events.

I am just wondering if i can accomplish this task in just one Query. Can you suggest me some query?

Here is table structure.
[image]

Currently i have this query.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_event ORDER BY event_date DESC;
```

This application is in Codeignitor framework and MySql is database type.

Comment: that's how do modern developers work - first get the job and then go ask on stackoverflow how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_event ORDER BY event_date DESC WHERE DATE(event_date) = DATE(NOW()) UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_event ORDER BY event_date DESC WHERE event_date >= NOW() UNION SELECT * FROM tlb_event ORDER_BY event_date DESC WHERE event_date < NOW()
```

Comment: I liked this query, but i dun have data type datetime for this field. Can you please suggest me other work around with this data type? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: just enclose all event_date and now()'s with date function like so: `DATE(even_date)` and `DATE(NOW())`

Comment: Thanks man, you just earned a lunch. Let me know when you want it.:)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ...
...
ORDER BY (event_date = curdate()) DESC,    // today's events
     (event_date > curdate()) DESC, // future events
     event_date DESC; // past events
```